# Listings moredelim option not working as expected

Tags: listings, delimiters

I'm having problems with the lstlistings package. I need to create my own language definition in which I have the keyword 'test' but also need to escape the keyword highlighting in one particular spot where it's part of a name 'variable test'. I've set a delimiter but it doesn't work as I expected it to. 'test' still gets highlighted as keyword. I've already tried using invisible delimiters but with the same result.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{script}{
    keywords={test,
    },
    morecomment=[s]{'}{'},
    morestring=[b]",
    sensitive=false,
}
\lstdefinestyle{default}{
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=\true,
    backgroundcolor=\color[HTML]{FEFDFF},
    breaklines=true,
    frame=single,
    keepspaces=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{orange}\emph,
    numbers=left,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    moredelim=[s][basicstyle]{variable}{test},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=default,language=script]
variable test
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: I've basically just replaced the space with an underscore. It's not the most elegant solution, but it works.